# MBP 6.1 compatibility with 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, macbook, macbook-pro

I installed 14.04 LTS on my MBP 6.1 (early 2010) and everything works flawlessly except for when I let my laptop go to sleep.

It wakes up, but when I try to log back in, it just crashed and reboots. Anyone encounter this issue and/or solved this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This thread might give you hints http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145047. Some guys switched to nvidia-experimental or the proprietary video driver and reinstalled apport.